# How to divide page into multiple colored sections

Tags: html, colors, background, divide

my question is how can I divide a background into multiple colored sections.  I'm pretty new to coding, so if you could maybe give me a brief explanation I would appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more information? What type of background?

Comment: uh, html? sorry, i really dont mean to be a fustration

Answer (score 2):

```
Code For Spiting the page  

<html>
<div align="top" style="width:1024;height:100;border:solid;border-width:2;background:#ccc;">
<img src="yourimage.jpg" height="100" width="1024"></img>
</div>

<div style="width:1024;height:200;background:#dedede;">
<div style="width:300;height:200;border:solid;border-width:2;float:left;background:#414141;"></div>
<div style="width:300;height:200;border:solid;border-width:2;float:right;background:#616161;"></div>
</div>

<div align="bottom" style="height:100;width:1024;border:solid;background:#868686;"">
<center>Hello World</center>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look into div's

[HTML div Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp)

then set a background in the CSS style

[CSS background-color](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp)

that's all think off with out having an example of that your trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

the way I did the different sections into colour was by doing different div sections for example:

div style="background-color:Lightblue

font color:"Black"

(Enter text)

/div

/font

br /br

div style="background-color:Black"

font color="white"

(Enter text)

/div

/font

if you dont want a break in between the you can take the br /br